# Why my service worker block the render?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am building a Progressive Web App. When I open my site on incognito, on the console printed what asset is being loaded by the SW. Then I realized while loading, the page is white blank. I assume the render is blocked while SW populating the asset.

Trying to make sure, I did it again with the Slow 3G connection. The result is same.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: The render is blocked while SW populating the asset]

How could this happen?

I thought SW has to be loaded on another thread and not blocking the render. (cmiiw)

***Edit:***

I registered the SW with this and **inlined** in the html.

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('/service-worker.js')
      .then(function(registration) {
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope)
      })
      .catch(function(ex) {
        console.warn(ex)
        console.warn('(This warning can be safely ignored outside of the production build.)')
      })
  }
```

I built the `service-worker.js` by using `sw-precache-webpack-plugin`. Here is my config.

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      minify: true,
      cacheId: 'sw-cache',
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/(login|logout|appauth|status|filtron|service-worker|.*\.pl|.*\.html)).*/],
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /^https:\/\/connect\.facebook\.net\//,
          handler: 'cacheFirst'
        },
      ],
      staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /assets\.json$/, /service-worker\.js$/, /manifest\.json$/],
    }),
```

Comment: I don't see how we can possibly answer this without more information, including how you're registering the service worker, what information is required for your initial render, etc. Clearly, assuming a properly-registered service worker, something that is required for rendering is behind these other things in the network queue. You don't have infinite parallel connections, so you need to ensure anything you need *right now* is requested before anything else.

Comment: I'll update my question with the information

Comment: I was loading my SW after load event. It was working, the page shows and then the SW populates all assets. What I am concerning is not the order of the load of the scripts, it doesn't matter where the SW is loaded, but why the SW doesn't populate the asset on background?

Comment: @AlfredCrosby Every synchronous JS blocks rendering, by design - it's not SW-specific. Where in HTML have you put this SW registration? Also, generally registering SW onload makes a lot of sense. It is not like this by default, probably to give you more control and handle cases when you want your SW to be in charge as soon as possible (guessing here).

Comment: I tried to register the SW at the end of the document. Yes, it blocks the render. The conclusion so far is SW blocks the render while it is populating the asset. So the only way is to register the SW after the load event.

Comment: The service worker does fetch assets "in the background", i.e. in a different thread. While fetching assets uses bandwidth, and isn't "free", it shouldn't stop code from executing on the main thread. I really don't understand how the service worker comes into play here, though, if you say that you've deferred registering your service worker until after the page has loaded. If the page has loaded, then you should see content on the page, and only at that point will the service worker event start up. So... it's not clear that your screenshots illustrate the same thing you describe.

Comment: Sorry, just to make it clear. I said it blocks the render when I registered the SW before load event and it is when the screenshot was taken. Then I came to the conclusion that I needed to load the SW right after load event.